# Are these threads using the same array?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a project to benchmark 2 sorting algorithms against each other. However, when the sorting finishes neither arrays are sorted, even if I run the same algorithm simultaneously. I think it may be an error occurring within threading where one algorithm is taking the calculated answer from the other.

It does work when only one algorithm is run.

Am I correct in thinking that this is down to one thread using the array of the other?

Here's the code where the error occurs (the algorithms are held within their own classes):

```
            string algorithmLeft = "";
            string algorithmRight = "";

            if (cboxDropDownLeft.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                algorithmLeft = cboxDropDownLeft.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
            if (cboxDropDownRight.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                algorithmRight = cboxDropDownRight.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }

            ThreadStart tsLeft = delegate ()
            {
                try
                {
                    switch (algorithmLeft)
                    {
                        case ("Bubble Sort"):
                            Bubble_Sort bubbleSort = new Bubble_Sort();
                            bubbleSort.sortArray();
                            break;

                        case ("Merge Sort"):
                            Merge_Sort mergeSort = new Merge_Sort();
                            mergeSort.sortArray();
                            break;

                        case ("Quick Sort"):
                            Quick_Sort quickSort = new Quick_Sort();
                            quickSort.sortArray();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                }

            };

            ThreadStart tsRight = delegate ()
            {
                try
                {
                    switch (algorithmRight)
                    {
                        case ("Bubble Sort"):
                            Bubble_Sort bubbleSort = new Bubble_Sort();
                            bubbleSort.sortArray();
                            break;

                        case ("Merge Sort"):
                            Merge_Sort mergeSort = new Merge_Sort();
                            mergeSort.sortArray();
                            break;

                        case ("Quick Sort"):
                            Quick_Sort quickSort = new Quick_Sort();
                            quickSort.sortArray();
                            break;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                }

            };

            if (algorithmLeft != "")
            {
                Thread tLeft = new Thread(tsLeft);
                tLeft.Start();
            }
            if (algorithmRight != "")
            {
                Thread tRight = new Thread(tsRight);
                tRight.Start();
            }
```

Bubble Sort:

```
        public override void sortArray()
        {
            try
            {
                int n = arrayToSort.Count - 1;

                for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < n; loop1++)
                {

                    for (int loop2 = n; loop2 > loop1; loop2--)
                    {
                        if (((IComparable)arrayToSort[loop2 - 1]).CompareTo(arrayToSort[loop2]) > 0)
                        {
                            object temp = arrayToSort[loop2];
                            arrayToSort[loop2] = arrayToSort[loop2 - 1];
                            arrayToSort[loop2 - 1] = temp;
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(speed);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

Merge Sort:

```
        public override void sortArray()
        {
            try
            {
                sort(arrayToSort, 0, arrayToSort.Count - 1);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }

        }

            public void sort(ArrayList arrayToSort, int left, int right)
        {
            if (left < right)
            {
                int m = left + (right - left) / 2;

                sort(arrayToSort, left, m);
                sort(arrayToSort, m + 1, right);
                merge(arrayToSort, left, m, right);
            }
        }

        public void merge(ArrayList data, int left, int mid, int right)
        {
            int i, j, k;
            int n1 = mid - left + 1;
            int n2 = right - mid;
            ArrayList L = new ArrayList(n1);
            ArrayList R = new ArrayList(n2);

            for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            {
                L.Add(data[left + i]);
            }

            for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                R.Add(data[mid + 1 + j]);
            }

            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            k = left;

            while (i < n1 && j < n2)
            {
                if (((IComparable)L[i]).CompareTo(R[j]) < 0)
                {
                    data[k] = L[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    data[k] = R[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }

            while (i < n1)
            {
                data[k] = L[i];
                i++;
                k++;
                Thread.Sleep(speed);
            }

            while (j < n2)
            {
                data[k] = R[j];
                j++;
                k++;
                Thread.Sleep(speed);
            }
        }
```

Quick Sort:

```
        public int partition(ArrayList arrayToSort, int left, int right)
        {
            int pivot = (int)arrayToSort[left];

            while (true)
            {
                while (((IComparable)arrayToSort[left]).CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
                {
                    left++;
                }

                while (((IComparable)arrayToSort[right]).CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
                {
                    right--;
                }

                if (left < right)
                {
                    object temp =arrayToSort[right];
                    arrayToSort[right] = arrayToSort[left];
                    arrayToSort[left] = temp;
                    Thread.Sleep(speed);
                }
                else
                {
                    return right;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void sortArray()
        {
            try
            {
                sort(arrayToSort, 0, arrayToSort.Count - 1);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }

        public void sort(ArrayList arr, int left, int right)
        {
            if (left < right)
            {
                int pivot = partition(arr, left, right);

                if (pivot > 1)
                {
                    sort(arr, left, pivot - 1);
                }

                if (pivot + 1 < right)
                {
                    sort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
                }
            }
        }
```

Algorithm for the creation of the 2 arrays that are to be sorted:

```
            ArrayCreator arrayCreator = new ArrayCreator();
            arrayCreator.createArray(arrayLeft);
            arrayRight = arrayLeft;
```

ArrayCreator:

```
        public void createArray(ArrayList array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int x = rnd.Next(1, 400);
                array.Add(x);
                Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Changing the line `arrayRight = arrayLeft` to `arrayRight = arrayLeft.Clone()` solved the issue as I was unintentionally trying to sort the same array instance simultaneously with 2 algorithms.

Comment: You did not show creation of the critical resource: `arrayLeft` / `arrayRight` ... are they the _same_ array?

Comment: And unrelated: consider making a ThreadStartFactory out of those two nearly identical switches ...

Comment: Yeah they are to start with (i.e. before the sorting begins).

Comment: If you want *us* to ignore the lines with `//Ignore this` comments, then just remove them. You should maybe add the class definitions for `Bubble_Sort`, `Heap_Sort`, `Merge_Sort` and `Quick_Sort` (or at least one of those).

Comment: Did you verify that each Algorithm works single-threaded?

Comment: Fildor means are they **reference identical** arrays? If there are two people in a room and I ask them both to sort the same shuffled deck of cards and they do not cooperate, they're going to have a hard time getting it in order.

Comment: What you want to do is make one array, shuffle it, and then *clone it*, and then ask the two sorts to each sort their own copy.

Comment: I believe the 2 arrays to be separate. It also isn't an issue with each individual algorithm. They work if I only use one, the issue occurs when 2 are used simultaneously (even if they are the same algorithm).

Comment: You also need to make sure that you only ever create a single `Random` instance per thread. Use the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute on a class-level field for that. Otherwise, you're going to get repeated values that aren't random.

Comment: What I mean about the arrays is that they are both declared separately. arrayLeft is then given a value and arrayRight is then set to the value of arrayLeft.

Comment: If you mean `arrayLeft=GetArray(); arrayRight=arrayLeft;` then they are referencing the same thing. That won't work

Comment: @B.Griffin: As Eric Lippert said you have to clone them. If you just set the value, you have two variables that point to the exact same array.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Meta-Knight. That makes sense now.

Comment: You might also consider not using `ArrayList` because your ints are boxed to objects which can cause more problems if you don't deep clone, not to mention the performance hit if you are investigating algorithm efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated that the sorting is working if a single thread is running one of the algorithms, but when you use different algorithms, then the result is no longer right. This means that the threads are preventing each-other from achieving success.

Let me explain: Let's assume you have two threads, T1 and T2. If both of them are comparing x and y then you have two possible scenarios

#### Scenario1

T1 compares x and y and realizes they need to be swapped
T1 swaps x and y
T2 copmares x and y and realizes they are in correct order

Result: Success

#### Scenario2

T1 compares x and y and realizes they need to be swapped
T2 compares x and y and realizes they need to be swapped
T1 swaps x and y
T2 swaps y and x

Result: Failure, T2 was making the comparison after T1 made the comparison, but before T1 made the swap.

As a result, this is unsafe. It is much better to let the Threads sort their own partition of the problem space and then mergesort the sorted subsets.

Comment: But while the values of the arrays are the same, both arrays are declared individually. Also, while this removes the issue, the purpose of this project is to make the speeds of the sorting algorithms comparable. The algorithms are both to _completely_ sort the arrays, individually.

Comment: @B.Griffin _"the purpose of this project is to make the speeds of the sorting algorithms comparable"_ So sort of a benchmark? In that case I'd suggest to _not_ let them run in parallel at all. If they happen to share any resource, they will have performance impacts on one another.

Comment: @B.Griffin in that case it makes more sense to create a clone of the input array for each of them and to avoid doing the sort on the very same arrays. A sequential run would be a possible alternative.

Comment: Could there be a Scenario 3: T1 and T2 try to swap x and y but don't do atomic swaps so the data becomes x and x?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, that's also possible. The solution is to not share the array you are to sort, but each sorting algorithm should have exclusive access to its own copy of the initial data-set, so any change a thread does would not happen for the other thread's data, making the threads independent from each-other.